# In Excel, how do I add values (running total) until and ONLY until a value is reached or breached?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Link to Google Sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6FWnOfwzSXr6DaDvdo7Ruw_4qy9C0YUmvJlEfoQLCU/edit?usp=sharing

What I need ? I have data in column A only. From A2 to A97. In B2, B3 etc etc, I want a formula that adds value in Column A from that particular Row and onwards until the value 100% is reached or breached. I found one formula (given below) for Count from elsewhere in Stackoverflow, but it works fine for certain rows and not others. ( this formula was suggested by the user @Jeeped )

`=MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2, 0,0,ROW($1:$99),1))<=100%)*ROW($1:$99),,))+1`
( if i want to copy this formula down, in all the subsequent rows, will it work ? ).
Please help me with where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance !

```
 100% ( should be reached or breached; then give output - Sum as well
   as Count )

   30%          8   Takes This and NEXT 7 rows to reach or breach 100%
   -65%         7   Takes This and NEXT 6 rows to reach or breach 100% 30%          6    10%            5    10%            4   
   -27%         3    44%            2    198%           1   This is correct 250%            5   This is wrong. 240% is already greater than 100%. So the result should be "1".
   -65%         11  
   -28%         8   
   -94%         6    125%           5   This is wrong. 128% is already greater than 100%. So the result should be "1".
   -18%         5    75%            3   
   -99%         5    135%           1    44%            3   
   -8%          2    250%           1   
   -19%         18  This is wrong. It should be 5.
   -78%         17   116%           16  
   -44%         15   183%           14  This is wrong 28%           17   4%         16  
   -84%         15   40%            14  
   -7%          13  
   -96%         12  
   -53%         9    163%           6   Wrong
   -81%         9   
   -30%         6   
   -31%         5   
   -65%         2    237%           1   
   -57%         4    164%           3   Wrong
   -87%         4    116%           1    62%            2    173%           30   53%            41   39%            100 Why 100 from here on ?
   -6%          100 
   -51%         100  138%           38  
   -14%         100  259%           100 
   -51%         100  44%            100 
   -94%         100 
   -85%         100 
   -25%         100 
   -10%         100  104%           100  76%            100 
   -61%         100  86%            100  87%            100 
   -14%         100 
   -68%         100 
   -95%         100 
   -100%            100 
   -94%         100  75%            100 
   -78%         100 
   -92%         100 
   -78%         15  This should be 4
   -78%         12   150%           1    150%           12
```

Comment: does it stop when 100% is reached? and leave the rest of the rows belwo blank?

Comment: Thanks for responding Ames. No, it does not stop. For EACH row, the formula is copied. The formula's outputs are : (1) How many more Rows it takes to arrive at or breach the value "100%" ? (2) Once the Count is known, evaluate the Sum value found.   I have included the formula only for Count. Please help me with Sum formula as well.  I do not know what happens in the last few rows, where the criterion cannot be reached at all. What output it gives ? For instance, if the last two rows contain (54%) and (20%) ( both in negative sign ), each of these two rows can never evaluate to 100% or more.

Comment: The above text looks unreadable. Is it possible to attach the sample Excel file ? Sorry I am a new user here, hence these questions. Thanks.

Comment: you could add a link to a google sheet

Comment: You need to reformat that data.

Comment: Please consider using a method such as [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to generate a data sample people can read and copy and paste for their own testing. Also,  see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as i don't think that much data is needed to demonstrate the problem at hand.

Comment: Link to Google Sheet :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6FWnOfwzSXr6DaDvdo7Ruw_4qy9C0YUmvJlEfoQLCU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @QHarr I wanted to demonstrate how inconsistent and randomly the formula works at various rows. That is why I have included so many rows of data.

Comment: @Sriram Point noted.

Comment: for this I think you will need a VBA to solve it instead of formula since there is a loop involved to recalculate next +=1 from current row until you get >=1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the formula you already have is very over complicated. If I understand your question correctly you want the totals in column B to continually increment until they hit 100% (or 1) then they just keep returning 1 thereafter.

This is simple to do. You simply put the calculation in an if statement with the condition is equal to or greater than 1 (because 1 == 100%) if the condition is true then return 1 otherwise return the result of the calculation.

There is an [example sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0nrde7g9I2weRFzyv9a0GMiHfJg3SgSVh00Swehz_A/edit?usp=sharing) (The formula in Google Sheets is the same as Excel in this case)

Otherwise in B2 you just need to take the value of A2 (as there is nothing to add it to at this point)
Then you put the following into B3 and copy it down:

```
=if(A3+B2 >=1, 1, A3+B2)
```

However a word of caution to the wise:

If you **ever** have negative values then this is not a good idea. Lets say you add 50% + 50% + 50% = 150% but in your case this will just = 100%. If we now add -25% the total is 75% instead of 125%

So just to be crystal clear, you should only use the above formula if you are certain that all the data in column A is going to be positive.